# facing an error running meld on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, meld, xming

did a fresh install of meld (3.14.2-1) on ubuntu 16.04, and running it gives the following error.

```
$ meld
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(meld:17993): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 282, in <module>
    setup_resources()
  File "/usr/bin/meld", line 191, in setup_resources
    Gtk.IconTheme.get_default().append_search_path(icon_dir)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'
```

I am using putty, and X11 forwarding is enabled as shown in this image:

[image: putty settings]

Further Xming is also running. And if i run meld from another 14.04 ubuntu machine, it works fine. Actually, i want to add meld as a graphical tool for git, and facing this issue.

Comment: The error message means you do *not* have working X11 forwarding.

Comment: @tripleee : any idea how to make it working. The same putty settings for x11 forwarding works fine for ubuntu 14.04 machine. Are there any prerequisites to check on 16.04 to make X11 forwarding work ?

Comment: Ubuntu isn't my cup of `$beverage`but my guess would be that the back and forth between X11 and Mir and Wayland might be what's biting you here. Maybe stock 16.04 simply does not support your use case. Not really a programming question anyway (perhaps try [ubuntu.se]?)